# How to have a calculation over the limits of Int32/64 for the product of an int and a float?

Tags: c#, biginteger

My application has to deal with calculating large numbers. How can I multiply an int and a float and get a product as a BigInteger without overflowing? Specifically, I have to get `"BaseCost" x ("multiplier" by the power of "level")`

I tested that "`new BigInteger(100000000000000000000000)`" doesn't work. So I don't think "`if(BigInteger > (BigInteger)(Int1 * float1))`" will work. It'll probably get overflowed in the "`(Int1 * float1)`" part.

Comment: Try unsigned int / unsigned long..

Comment: Convert to `BigInteger` first, then do arithmetic. It's always like that.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try

Comment: I tried `return (BigInteger)(new BigInteger(BaseCost) * Mathf.Pow(CostMultiplier, Level));` bur apparantely you can't multifly float by BigInteger.

Comment: `BigInteger.Multiply (new BigInteger(BaseCost), Mathf.Pow(CostMultiplier, Level))` did not work either...

Comment: @HMS-France Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [edit] your question to include the full source code as a [mcve]. Include all the error messages you get and the problems you have. "Do not work" is not a helpful description of your problem.

Comment: `BigInteger.Parse("100000000000000000000000")` ?

Comment: If you need big floats, BigInteger won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is how I fixed the issue. I used [BigDecimal](https://gist.github.com/JcBernack/0b4eef59ca97ee931a2f45542b9ff06d) from JcBernack in GitHub and this is the following code.

```
private BigInteger Example
{
    get
    {
        return (BigInteger)(new BigDecimal(Int1) * Float2);
    }
}
```

I used a BigDecimal class as I couldn't multiply BigInteger with a float. Also, before using the class I made sure to add a BigInteger caster (from uhDreamer's comment there).

```
public static explicit operator BigInteger(BigDecimal value)
{
    BigDecimal floored = value.Floor();
    return floored.Mantissa * BigInteger.Pow(10, floored.Exponent);
}
```

And an Int constructor.

```
public BigDecimal(int t)
{
    Exponent = 0;
    Mantissa = t;
    Normalize();
    if(AlwaysTruncate)
    {
        Truncate();
    }
}
```

Now, for developers who just need to multiply integers, they can do this `Int1(BigInteger) * Int2`.

And, of course, don't forget the System.Numerics namespace.

Comment: To mark this issue as solved, you can click the tick/check mark against the answer that most helped you. You are most welcome to mark your own in this fashion if you wish.